# java7 SecureRandom performance on MacOSX

Tags: macos, random, java-7

I'm running tomcat7 with jdk7 on MacOSX Mavericks DP3.
Everything goes well , and it only takes 500 ms to start up .
But suddenly, it slows down to 35 seconds.

The log message shows SecureRandom is the root cause.
Thanks for google, I found it's a jre bug , and following code to verify:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
class JRand {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Ok: " +
           SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").nextLong());
     }
}
```

Yes. The simplest code also takes 35 seconds. 
But it seems that all those related solutions do not work for me.
Both /dev/random and /dev/urandom are not block devices on Mac.

```
cat /dev/random | hexdump -C
```

output very quickly!

When switched back to jre6, it's very fast to generate randoms.
Download the latest jdk8-ea, the problem still exists.

In fact , not only tomcat slows down significantly, Netbeans, glassfish are all affected. 
After struggling with for hours, I gave up at last.

This morning, when I came to office, plugged in Ethernet, guess what ?
It recovered!

So my question is , what happens behind ? It's really weird.

Thanks.

Comment: Now it comes again.
The profile tool shows it's blocked when invoking :

    java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(hostname)

from java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost() 

:'(

Comment: it's a native method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, resolved.
Get InetAddress.java source code (can copy from IDE);
modify method getLocalHost from

```
String local = impl.getLocalHostName();
```

to :

```
String local = "localhost"; // impl.getLocalHostName();
```

recompile it, and add java.net.InetAddress.class back to JDK/jre/lib/rt.jar.

RESOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change InetAddress, other code may rely on it. Instead, change sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator::getSystemEntropy() to not use the local ip address. (How secure is that anyway?) As an added bonus, you now become slightly more secure via obscurity :)